# Search / Find / Replace in Firefox Developer Tools Debugger

Tags: firefox, find-and-replace, debugger, firefox-developer-tools

I've looked all over but I can't find anything (not even in the [***MDN Firefox Developer Tools*** Help Pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)) which explains how, when I'm looking at the ***Debugger*** in **Firefox Developer Tools** I can request to `Find` a snippet of javascript and then cycle through all the occurences of that snippet / substring in the `.js` document I'm looking at.

Normally, I copy/paste the entire script to Sublime Text 3 and then start cycling through using `Find` there.

But this is starting to feel pretty time intensive / over-elaborate.

Is there any way I can initiate `Find` in the Debugger itself?

**N.B.** I know about `[CTRL] +[SHIFT] + F` which pulls up a list of line references in all available javascript files, but that's less useful, because I'm usually looking to find a snippet of code within its surrounding context, to know that I'm looking at the right instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows and Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (macOS) while the focus is within the Debugger panel and a search bar will open.

Enter the search string and then you can cycle through all occurrences of the searched string by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to search backwards, or use the arrow buttons at the end of the search bar.

There's also a [dedicated page on MDN for all the keyboard shortcuts available in the Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Keyboard_shortcuts).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, @SebastianZartner - that was exactly what I needed.